# Can collection be passed as a parameter inside of org.quartz.JobDataMap?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ for scheduling jobs in our project. There is a handy feature to trigger a job manually with some parameters. This is typically used for a dry-run or re-running a failed job with certain parameters. Let's say, I would like to pass a list of some ids to a Job that extends [QuarzJobBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/QuartzJobBean.html). I am passing a [JobDataMap](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.2/org/quartz/JobDataMap.html) and it works perfectly fine with String/Integer/Long values, but is it possible to get a List?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
public String run(JobDataMap dataMap) {
    List<Integer> ids = (List<Integer>) dataMap.get("ids");
    log.info("start the job");
    // run the job
    log.info("end Status Report job");
    return "ok"
}
```

And getting an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.lang.String and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Comment: as per the Quartz APIs, dataMap.get("ids") one value. so you need to get that value and add it to the list.

Comment: Error is `ClassCastException` so probably what you, getting is a `String` object and you try to cast it to `List<?>`, check whether the type of value you get and try to map it to list properly.